# Savinging and generating AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, realm

I'm having some serious issues here trying to save a `AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject` in Swift.

I'm using this library: https://github.com/yeahdongcn/RSBarcodes_Swift, but it has terrible documentation.

Basically, I can scan fine and can handle that scan and future scans to build a "Scan History" type screen... The problem comes in when I restart the application - my Scan History is empty (obviously). I need to save these scans locally somehow but I'm not sure how to do that.

I've tried saving the attributes of a scan but rebuilding it after app restart is proving to be just as tricky. I've tried saving them as custom objects (which would be ideal and is possible - except for the `AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject` part as I get errors like `non-property` etc)

I'm approaching the point where I think I should try something like Realm but I've never used it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't easily save `AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject` to Core Data, because it's not a supported type and does not conform to `NSCoding`. Switching to Realm won't make any difference, because it has the same restrictions (it can't just save an `AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject`). The reasons are similar-- in both cases `AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject` isn't a subclass of the appropriate type, and it's not one of the supported property types.

What you need to do depends on how exactly your scan history UI is supposed to look. Saving the `AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject` is almost certainly not the best approach, though (you might be able to add `NSCoding` through a Swift extension but it's probably the wrong answer even if it works). There are a couple of possibilities:

1. Save **the data represented by the scanned code** instead of the code itself. You get this from the `stringValue` property of `AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject`. When you want to show the scan history, **generate new images** to display. This is straightforward using Core Image-- `COQRCodeGenerator`, `CIAztecCodeGenerator`, `CICode128BarcodeGenerator`, and `CIPDF417BarcodeGenerator` are all built in.
2. Take a photo at the same time as you scan the image, and display the photo as the scan history entry. Include the `stringValue` of the scanned code in the UI so that people can see what the image represents.

Comment: Thank Tom... I ended up doing what you said in option 1 before you posted. However I'm glad you mentioned the fact that saving `AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject` is a bad idea. I eventually realised this but it's nice to have confirmation...